# Short story about astronauts landing on planet and being mind controlled when falling asleep

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

As a child I read a SciFi short story where I think two astronauts (emergency?) landed on a planet, and as soon as they fell asleep they began to be controlled by the local (immaterial) species. The protagonist fights to not fall asleep, and the story ends with him finally surrendering, if I remember correctly. The airlock also could have played a role, but I'm not sure.

These are very vague memories, must have been in a short story collection from the local library, and it was probably late 80s or early 90s when I read it.

Comment: If it was **one** astronaut instead of two, I'd have suggested Ray Bradbury's "Asleep in Arfmageddon" a.k.a. "Perchance to Dream", which you can read here: https://archive.org/details/Donald_A._Wollheim_ed._Avon_Fantasy_Reader_no._11_1949/page/n79/mode/2up

Answer (score 4):

Could be Ray Bradbury's *Asleep in Armageddon*. There was only one astronaut, but there were two sets of aliens both wanting to use his body.

Comment: Thank you, just read it and it's a great story wich has a very similar vibe to the one I was looking for. I don't think it's the exact same one I'm searching for as I don't remember any historic battles in it. I'm pretty sure there was another human that fell victim to being taken over. Also I read it in German back then and there doesn't seem to be a translation of _Asleep in Armageddon_. It's highly likely though that the story I read was inspired by this one.